# TFRecords and Dataset API for even minibatches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have about 3.1 million records which are split into two TFRecords files. One conatains positive classes (~217K) and the other contains negative classes (~2.9MM). I'm trying to use the Dataset API to interleave the records in such a way that each batch has a 50/50 split. In order to use up all data, I'd like to repeat the positive examples such that all negative examples are used.

What ends up happening now is that it starts even, but when positive records run out, only negative records appear in the batch.

I believe this can be solved in my code below by adding a `.repeat()` if the filename is `train_pos.tfrecords` however, I am unable to figure out how to modify the `_get_files()` function to do so. I think this is likely a simple answer I'm missing?

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("train_*.tfrecords")       
def _get_files(x):
    return tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x).shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

dataset = files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
    lambda x: _get_files(x), cycle_length=2))\
    .batch(self.batch_size)\
    .map(_parse_line, num_parallel_calls=6)\
    .repeat(1)\
    .prefetch(2)
```

Comment: Use `repeat(-1)` so that the data cannot be exhausted.

Comment: But what if I only want train_pos.tfrecords to repeat indefinitely, and I want train_neg.tfrecords to repeat once? Such that everything stops when train_neg.tfrecords has reached the end. Is this possible?

Comment: You can create two datasets by calling twice `tf.data.Dataset` with the relevant TF Records. By the way, I would advise you to divide your data into much smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two datasets by calling twice `tf.data.Dataset` with the relevant TF Records:

```
files1 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...)
files2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...)
```

and use `repeat(-1)` to make the two datasets inexhaustible.
Then, you can use the output of the two batched datasets and concatenate them in order to have a balanced batch.